# Explicitly setting size and making it to resizable of my Dialog?

Tags: java

I have created a My custom Dialog which extends org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog. But whenever it displays, it displays with a small size and i cant resize it also. So i wanted to know how to set its size while creation and how to make it resizable.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make the dialog resizeable, add this to your class:

```
protected boolean isResizable() {
    return true;
}
```

Usually, you don't have to give it a size but simply specify a layout. The dialog will then layout itself and select a size which fits all elements. So to make it bigger, find the widget which you want to make bigger and set size constraints on it. If you use the default `GridLayout`, create a `GridData` instance and install it on the widget with `setLayoutData()`.

In `GridData`, use `widthHint` or `heightHint` for a different preferred size or even `minimumWidth`/`minimumHeight` to make sure it doesn't shrink below a certain size.

For more about layouts, [read this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Comment: Also, if you see the alternate suggestion to make a dialog resizable by setting the `SWT.RESIZE` bit, note the API documentation for `Dialog.isResizable()` - "Individual dialogs may always set the shell style to ensure that a dialog is resizable, *but using this method ensures that resizable dialogs will be created withthe same set of style bits.*"  It sounds like the approach suggested in the answer above should be preferred.